# Dispatch in dependencies. Where is true? We should or not to add dispatch in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux

We should or not to add dispatch in dependencies of react hooks? Is there exact opinion about this thing? Who knows true? Some says yes, some no

```
const Component = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(someAction());
    }, [dispatch]);
    return (
        <div>
            Component
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is good idea to add the dispatch function to the dependancy array, depends on what you want to reach. If you want that your useEffect is executed every time your "dispatch" function changes, then the answer would be **yes**. If you don't want to track the dispatch function, then the answer would be **no**.

In general the dispatch function does not change at all, thats why adding it to the dependancy array will be with no difference. But there are some libraries and cases, that may change the function assignment, which could cause unwanted re-run of the useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no opinion, values coming from 3rd party libraries **should be in dep array**.

That's because you can't know if its value persists (unless it mentioned in docs or you check the source code).

Removing it from the dependencies will get you an eslint warning [`react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin).

Specific for Redux's `useDispatch`, the value [is persisted,](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#examples) so removing it won't make a difference.

> Note: like in React's `useReducer`, the returned dispatch function identity is stable and won't change on re-renders.

But as mentioned, it may not be true for other libraries, so having it in dependencies is an extra safety without fighting the linter.